# Proving a category is *not* cartesian closed?

Tags: category-theory

Are there any general techniques for proving a category is *not* cartesian closed? Do cartesian closed categories have nice, easily checked properties that finitely bicomplete distributive categories typically do not have?

Comment: Cartesian closure means that $X\times -$ is a left adjoint and thus preserves *arbitrary* colimits, so if it doesn't the category isn't cartesian closed.

Comment: Ah, right. And, if in fact each of these functors preserves all colimits, then ``morally'' they should all have adjoints, and thus the category is very likely to be cartesian closed?

Comment: More or less.  For example, via the [adjoint functor theorem](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/adjoint+functor+theorem) for locally finitely presentable categories $X\times -$ preserving all colimits is equivalent to it being a left adjoint, and so if that holds for all $X$, then the category is cartesian closed.  In general, though, it could still fail to be cartesian closed of course, but yeah, it would be a pretty strong hint that the category probably is cartesian closed.

Comment: Thanks! If you want to put your first comment up as an answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A cartesian closed category means for every object $X$, $X\times -$ is a left adjoint, and thus preserves arbitrary colimits.  So typically what you would do is find some colimit which $X\times -$ does not preserve, maybe also by picking a clever choice of $X$.  Usually not too much cleverness is required.  Often some kind of "infinite" colimit works best.  I would say this is how failure of cartesian closure is usually noted.  I don't recall any examples where someone has actively sought after the failure of cartesian closure.

As the [adjoint functor theorem](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/adjoint+functor+theorem) suggests, if you can't find a colimit that $X\times -$ doesn't preserve for any $X$, then this is a strong hint that the category probably is cartesian closed, particularly when the category is cocomplete, though it could still fail for other reasons.  For locally presentable categories in particular, cocontinuity is equivalent to being a left adjoint.

If your category passes this battery of tests, you'll probably just need to use the definition of cartesian closure directly to show why it fails to be cartesian closed (if it does).  As a side note, the above applies to monoidal closure as well.